# Using numba.jit with scipy.integrate.ode

Tags: python, scipy, ode, numerical-integration, odeint

Using [`numba.jit`](http://numba.pydata.org/) to speed up right-hand-side calculations for `odeint` from [`scipy.integrate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html) works fine:

```python
from scipy.integrate import ode, odeint
from numba import jit

@jit
def rhs(t, X):
    return 1

X = odeint(rhs, 0, np.linspace(0, 1, 11))
```

However using `integrate.ode` like this:

```python
solver = ode(rhs)
solver.set_initial_value(0, 0)
while solver.successful() and solver.t < 1:
    solver.integrate(solver.t + 0.1)
```

produces the following error with the decorator `@jit`:

```
capi_return is NULL
Call-back cb_f_in_dvode__user__routines failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sandbox/numba_cubic.py", line 15, in <module>
    solver.integrate(solver.t + 0.1)
  File "/home/pgermann/Software/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ode.py", line 393, in integrate
    self.f_params, self.jac_params)
  File "/home/pgermann/Software/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ode.py", line 848, in run
    y1, t, istate = self.runner(*args)
TypeError: not enough arguments: expected 2, got 1
```

Any ideas how to overcome this?

Comment: Does it work without the `jit`?  Your `rhs` takes to arguments, the `t` that the solver varies, and the `X` that you supply (via the extra parameters tuple).

Comment: Yes, without the `jit` it works fine. What do you mean by extra parameters tuple?

Comment: I have similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a wrapper function, but I think it will not improve your performance for small rhs functions.

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def rhs(t, X):
    return 1

def wrapper(t, X):
    return rhs(t, X)

solver = ode(wrapper)
solver.set_initial_value(0, 0)
while solver.successful() and solver.t < 1:
solver.integrate(solver.t + 0.1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know a reason or solution, however in this case [Theano](https://theano.readthedocs.org/) helped a lot to speed up the calculation. Theano essentially compiles numpy expressions, so it only helps when you can write the rhs as expression of multi-dimensional arrays (while `jit` knows `for` and friends). It also knows some algebra and optimizes the calculation.

Besides Theano can compile for the GPU (which was my reason to try `numba.jit` in the first place). However using the GPU turned out to only improve performance for huge systems (maybe one million equations) due to the overhead.